# How would I redraw the lives count in my game

Tags: javascript, game-development, draw, p5.js

I'm making a game in which you try to click the darker circle from a group of randomly placed circles. When you click the correct circle, it re-randomizes it. When you click the incorrect circle, it's supposed to decrease the lives count and redraw it but instead, draws initially and doesn't update. When you click 3 wrong circles, it clears everything (and will display a "you died" screen) but when you click the right circle, just clears the non-updating lives count but the lives system still works.

```
const circlesToMake = 50;
let circles, r, g, b, lives;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 450);
  background(32);
  noStroke();
  setupCircles();
  drawCircles();
  fill(0);
  noLoop();
}

function setupCircles() {
  circles = []
  lives = 3;
  r = random(20, 255)
  g = random(20, 255)
  b = random(20, 255)

  while (circles.length < circlesToMake) {
    const circle = {
      x: random(width),
      y: random(height),
      r: 20,
      d: 40
    };

    let overlapping = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < circles.length; j++) {
      const other = circles[j];
      const d = dist(circle.x, circle.y, other.x, other.y);

      if (d < circle.r + other.r) {
        overlapping = true;
        break;
      } else if (circle.x < 0 + circle.d 
        || circle.x > width - circle.d) {
        overlapping = true;
        break;
      } else if (circle.y < 0 + circle.d || circle.y > height - circle.d) {
        overlapping = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (!overlapping) {
      circles.push(circle);
    }
  }
}

function drawCircles() {
  clear();
  circles.forEach(c => {
    fill(r, g, b, 200); ellipse(c.x, c.y, c.r * 2, c.r * 2);
  });

  fill(r, g, b, 220); // make the target easy to identify for development purposes
  const target = circles[0];
  ellipse(target.x, target.y, target.r * 2, target.r * 2);
}

function youDied() {
  clear();
  print("e");
}

function draw() {
  text(`lives: ${lives}`, 20, 20);
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (dist(mouseX, mouseY, circles[0].x, circles[0].y) < circles[0].r) {
    setupCircles();
    drawCircles();
  } else {
    const anyClicked = circles.some(c => dist(mouseX, mouseY, c.x, c.y) < c.r);
    if (anyClicked && --lives === 0) {
      youDied();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77963683/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-user-clicks-the-wrong-circle-from-an-array-p5-j

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534569/6133426) seems like a good place to start. In short - you would have to call `draw()` again, but you would need to clear the previous text (and only that) to avoid overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

Please could you provide more clear steps as to what you want the program to do. I will be able to help then. Code looks good, when I understand what you want I will be able to help you.